# Bootstrap 5 input group not adjusting vertically on mobile - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Using boostrap5.2.3. I have an input group that display a set of spans of ".input-group-text" with inputs of ".form-control".
It works as I needed on a computer screen but doesn't adjust vertically on mobile phone.

my current code is as follow (trying not to use row/col-sm):

```
<div class="container">
    <hr>
    <h5>1st step: Type the valuations criteria:</h5>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg input-group-sm mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom"
            title="The search will include properties sold within the radius">Radius:</span>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="radiusMetersId" value=300 min="100"
            max="10000" step="100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="(meters)">

        <span class="input-group-text">Sale type:</span>
        <select class="form-control" id="saleTypeId">
            <option value="apartment">Apartment</option>
            <option value="house">House</option>
            <option value="all">All</option>
        </select>

        <span class="input-group-text">Sqm:</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" value="50" min="5" max="100000" step="5" id="sqmId">

        <span class="input-group-text">Rooms:</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" value="3" min="0" max="10" step="1" id="roomsId">
    </div>
</div>
```

I use these headers:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

and these scripts:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

See bellow pics: (last pic being what I would like on mobile):

[image: Computer display:]

[image: Mobile disply]

[image: Desired display on mobile]

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <hr>
    <h5>1st step: Type the valuations criteria:</h5>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg input-group-sm mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="The search will include properties sold within the radius">Radius:</span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="radiusMetersId" value=300 min="100" max="10000" step="100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="(meters)">

      <span class="input-group-text">Sale type:</span>
      <select class="form-control" id="saleTypeId">
        <option value="apartment">Apartment</option>
        <option value="house">House</option>
        <option value="all">All</option>
      </select>

      <span class="input-group-text">Sqm:</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" value="50" min="5" max="100000" step="5" id="sqmId">

      <span class="input-group-text">Rooms:</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" value="3" min="0" max="10" step="1" id="roomsId">
    </div>
  </div>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Adding media query can do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using media queries we can achieve it

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .input-group-sm .input-group-text,
  .input-group-sm .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 0.25rem!important;
  }
  .input-group-sm .input-group-text {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .input-group-sm .input-group-text,
  .input-group-sm .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 0.25rem!important;
  }
  .input-group-sm .input-group-text {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <hr>
  <h5>1st step: Type the valuation criteria:</h5>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg input-group-sm mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text custom-label" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="The search will include properties sold within the radius">Radius:</span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="radiusMetersId" value="300" min="100" max="10000" step="100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="(meters)">

    <span class="input-group-text custom-label">Sale type:</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="saleTypeId">
      <option value="apartment">Apartment</option>
      <option value="house">House</option>
      <option value="all">All</option>
    </select>

    <span class="input-group-text custom-label">Sqm:</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="50" min="5" max="100000" step="5" id="sqmId">

    <span class="input-group-text custom-label">Rooms:</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="3" min="0" max="10" step="1" id="roomsId">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this defintely work. I was under the impression that it was already "managed" by boostrap css. for instanc when i use col-sm, it does show my blocks veritcally on mobile. I was expecting the same with input-group-sm... Any idea? Or is the actual way to do that with boostrap. tx a lot

Comment: Not 100% sure, You need to remove the gutters and do lot of modifications if you wanna use bootstrap straight awayI guess . This would be the easiest approach. Let's see if anyone answers

Comment: I've just realized that using input-group-sm makes the span text show in small even with a computer and input-group-lg seems to be ignored...

Comment: What so you mean? In desktop the alignment is not working?

Comment: @Teja yes on desktop. if you use the snipset, you will notice that the size of the text inputs is actually the small size, not the default.

Comment: @Teja I ended up using Sai's solution without the extra sm and lg classes.